# useing ionic ng-model returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

[view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjWUv.png)

[controller img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYInW.png)

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.login

Comment: create a sample plnkr

Comment: Write `$scope.data = {};` at very first line of your controller and then try.

Comment: I tried it like this :  $scope.data = { };
    alert($scope.data.username);   but it still did not work: [alert:undefined]

Comment: fix :  $scope.data = { };
    alert(data.username);   and  I am very corious about that it  really works .   thinks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

passing parameter is wrong. change it to

```
ng-click=login(data.username,data.password)
```

then, in controller

```
$scope.login = function(username,password){
   $scope.username = username;
   $scope.password = password;
...........
}
```